# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str while parsing JSON

Tags: python, json

I am trying to print out at least one key value from the returned Json, as following [this basic tutorial](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/json/)

```
response=None    
booking_source = 'sourceBusinessName'
api_request ='http://api.com'
r = requests.get(api_request)
while response is None:
    response = r.content.decode('utf-8')
    data = json.loads(response)
    print (data[booking_source])
    return HttpResponse(data[booking_source])
```

But it returns `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`
 probably because I am giving an string instead of an integer to `data` when printing, but then what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: You're assuming the JSON has an object at the top level.

Comment: `if (booking_source) in data:print (data[booking_source])...`may better

Comment: How do you access an array while parsing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `requests` you can skip the decoding of the response and parsing it as JSON by using the response's `json` method:

```
r = requests.get(api_request)
data = r.json()
print data    # so you can see what you're dealing with
```

At this point I suggest dumping out the value of `data` so that you can see the structure of the JSON data. Probably it is a JSON array (converted to a Python list) and you simply need to take the first element of that array before accessing the dictionary, but it's difficult to tell without seeing the actual data. You might like to add a sample of the data to your question.

Comment: Yes, it is an array of objects. How do you access the array first then ?

Comment: @xavier: use an integer subscript or slice, e.g. `data[0]` will give you the first item of the list. Possibly `data[0]` will give you the dictionary that you are expecting... can't tell without seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is an array at the top level, but you're trying to address it as if it were:

```
{
  "sourceBusinessName": {
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the question is then, how do you access an array ?

Comment: Can we see your JSON? In your example, it would be `data[0]`, `data[1]`, etc.